# The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query filter expression

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to filter standard Calendar events via SharePoint web api and my query looks like this:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('calendar')/items?$filter=( EventDate  ge  datetime'2013-01-26T22:00:00Z')&$select=Title,EventDate,ID
```

Query doesn't work and I receive this error:

> The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query filter expression

Error Details:

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query filter expression."},"innererror":{"message":"The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query filter expression.","type":"Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","stacktrace":"   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemEntityCollectionCamlQueryBuilder.CheckFieldRefUsage(SPField field, FieldRefUsage fieldRefUsage)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemEntityCollectionCamlQueryBuilder.SetFieldRef(XmlWriter writer, String fieldPath, FieldRefUsage fieldRefUsage, Action`1 attributeAction)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemEntityCollectionCamlQueryBuilder.SetWhereBinaryOp(XmlWriter writer, EdmParserNode parseNode)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemEntityCollectionCamlQueryBuilder.SetViewQuery(SPQuery query, XmlWriter writer, StringBuilder sb)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemEntityCollectionCamlQueryBuilder.BuildCamlQuery()\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemEntityCollectionCamlQueryBuilder..ctor(SPList list, RESTfulQuery restQuery, Nullable`1 itemId)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemEntityCollection.TryWriteAsOData(ODataWriter writer, RESTfulQuery query, ProxyContext proxyContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.Write(Object value, Uri path, ODataWriter writer, RESTfulQuery query, ProxyContext proxyContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.Process()\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest()\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestService.ProcessQuery(Stream inputStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer)","internalexception":{"message":"The field 'EventDate' of type 'DateTime' cannot be used in the query filter expression.","type":"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","stacktrace":""}}}}
```

Is it possible somehow to use fields type of DateTime in filter query expressions?

Update:
I found that I can do this via ListData.svc, e.g.

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Calendar?$filter=StartTime+ge+datetime'2011-11-23'
```

More details here - http://itblog.wolthaus.net/2011/12/rest-filter-datetime/

I tried to remove the time part from the /_api/web/ query, e.g.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('calendar')/items?$filter=( EventDate  ge  '2013-01-26')&$select=Title,EventDate,ID
```

But it didn't help and I got the same error.

Comment: Did you by any chance try to strip the 'time' portion ?

Comment: yes and it doesn't work either. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the web service (older, non-REST) endpoint. That's what I'm using in my project. The REST endpoint has many issues with few other Odata constructs too (ex $skip).

```
https://.../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Calendar?$select=Title,EventDate,ID&$filter=EventDate ge datetime'2013-01-26'
```

Comment: thank you! I found this as well, and you can see it in my question under Update part 7 years ago :/